# Why does my Tailwind styles not apply until I define them again?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a problem with my Tailwind classes.

I created a new component in the component directory and I placed my Button component there.

However, any time I restart the project in terminal the styles don't affect my button until I define them again manually. Here are my `tailwind.config.css`, `Button.js` and the `Navbar.js` files:

`tailwind.config.css`:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: '#FFD700',
        secondary: '#00CED1',
        accent: '#FF6347',
        success: '#32CD32'
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

`Button.js`:

```
'use client'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Button = ({ children, color }) => {

    const [colorPicker, setColorPicker] = useState('')
    const [colorWeight, setColorWeight] = useState(0)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        switch (color) {
        case 'primary':
            setColorPicker('amber')
            setColorWeight(300)
            break;
        case 'secondary':
            setColorPicker('teal')
            setColorWeight(500)
            break;
        case 'seccess':
            setColorPicker('lime')
            setColorWeight(600)
            break;
        case 'accent':
            setColorPicker('red')
            setColorWeight(500)
            break;
    }
    }, [color])
    

  return (
    <div>
        <button className={`bg-${color} px-4 py-1 rounded-xl hover:bg-${colorPicker}-${colorWeight} focus:bg-${colorPicker}-${colorWeight + 100} focus:ring-4 focus:ring-${colorPicker}-${colorWeight - 200} duration-200 text-white`}>
            {children}
        </button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Button
```

`Navbar.js`

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import Button from './Button';

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='flex justify-between items-center'>
        <div>
          <div className='flex'>
            <img src="" alt="Logo" />
            <p>Crossant</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <ul className='flex gap-3 items-center'>
            <Link href='/'>
              <li>Home</li>
            </Link>
            <Link href='/about'>
              <li>About me</li>
            </Link>
            <Link href='/posts'>
              <li>Posts</li>
            </Link>
            <Link href='/login'>
              <li>
              <Button color='primary'>Login</Button>
              </li>
            </Link>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could:

- Have a dictionary for `color` to Tailwind class names:

  ```
  const Button = ({ children, color }) => {
    let classes = '';

    switch (color) {
      case 'primary':
        classes = 'bg-primary hover:bg-amber-300 focus:bg-amber-400 focus:ring-amber-100';
        break;
      case 'secondary':
        classes = 'bg-secondary hover:bg-teal-500 focus:bg-teal-600 focus:ring-teal-300';
        break;
      case 'seccess':
        classes = 'bg-seccess hover:bg-lime-600 focus:bg-lime-700 focus:ring-lime-400';
        break;
      case 'accent':
        classes = 'bg-accent hover:bg-red-500 focus:bg-red-600 focus:ring-red-300'
        break;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <button className={`px-4 py-1 rounded-xl focus:ring-4 duration-200 text-white ${classes}`}>
          {children}
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  ```

  Refactored to an object dictionary:

  ```
  const CLASSES = {
    primary: 'bg-primary hover:bg-amber-300 focus:bg-amber-400 focus:ring-amber-100',
    secondary: 'bg-secondary hover:bg-teal-500 focus:bg-teal-600 focus:ring-teal-300',
    seccess: 'bg-seccess hover:bg-lime-600 focus:bg-lime-700 focus:ring-lime-400',
    accent: 'bg-accent hover:bg-red-500 focus:bg-red-600 focus:ring-red-300,
  };

  const Button = ({ children, color }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className={`px-4 py-1 rounded-xl focus:ring-4 duration-200 text-white ${CLASSES[color]}`}>
          {children}
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
  ```
- [`safelist` the classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes), if you have a limited number of known colors:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    safelist: [
      { pattern: /^bg-(primary|secondary|seccess|accent)$/ },
      {
        pattern: /^bg-(amber|teal|lime|red)-300$/,
        variants: ['hover'],
      },
      // …
    ],
    // …
  ];
  ```

Comment: @Wogjn I appriciate you for the time you spent on my question.